# Why is my Geoserver map off to one side?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am trying to load a map to display search results and when the map is loaded, it does not fill the modal that is supposed to contain it. I have tried changing the CRS between epsg:4326 and epsg:3857 to see if it was the projection that was messed up. Here is a screenshot of the problem, it should fill the entire modal:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the modal is actually wider than what the map element looks like?  This looks like an html issue...

Comment: Not sure what is happening, but got the same issue. In my case I had two divs and a show-and-hide with angularJs and then I got this issue. I also have a resize css directive, which maybe does not get trickered correctly. After window resize all works, on first load like the OP's.

Comment: I do not have access to this server all the time, I think it could have been Internet Explorer that messed it up because it seems to work with firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue! IE 9 does not play well with OpenLayers 3!

Comment: why downvote? That is what was wrong with my map.